# Varip only detect ta.crossunder but not ta.crossover

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

I'm trying to detect missing signal through replay using varip, and it seems like it only detect the crossunder missing signal but not the crossover missing signal. For crossover it only shows after the crossover has occurred.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test Script", overlay = true)

ma1 = ta.ema(close, 5)
ma2 = ta.ema(close, 25)

emaCross = ta.crossover(ma1, ma2)
emaCross2 = ta.crossunder(ma1, ma2)

// Plot Indicators
plot(ma1, title='MA1', color=color.new(color.purple, 0))
plot(ma2, title='MA2', color=color.new(color.orange, 0))

varip buyFlag = false

if barstate.isnew
buyFlag:= false
else
if emaCross
    buyFlag := true
plotshape(buyFlag, color = color.purple, location = location.abovebar)

varip sellFlag = false

if barstate.isnew
sellFlag:= false
else
if emaCross2
    sellFlag := true
plotshape(sellFlag, color = color.orange, location=location.belowbar)

plotshape(emaCross, title='Buy Signal', text='B', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0),      style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0))
plotshape(emaCross2, title='Short Signal', text='S', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0))
```

I'm trying to detect missing signal through replay using varip, and it seems like it only detect the crossunder missing signal but not the crossover missing signal. For crossover it only shows after the crossover has occurred.